# How do I write on a file without clean it?

Tags: php, fwrite

How do I write on a file without clean the file using fwrite function?
  I would like to write skiping a line using fwrite in a text file.

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, "Some text");
  fwrite($fp,"More texto in another line");
 fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Look at the [different modes for `fopen`](http://php.net/manual/function.fopen.php).

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning it? Also, why not add a newline first?

Answer (score 2):

Set your open mode to "append" instead of "write" (see the [documentation for `fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)):

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'a');
```

If you are on Windows, you may want to consider using the `t` flag to denote the file you are opening as a text file, so that the proper line-ending character is being used (`\r\n` instead of just `\n` for Windows):

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'at');
```

Now, to add your text onto new lines, make sure to use [`PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) for the newline character character to ensure that the right newline characters are being written for the right OSs:

```
fwrite($fp, PHP_EOL . 'Some text');
fwrite($fp, PHP_EOL . 'More text on another line');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change mode in fopen function from 'w' to 'a'

```
 $fp = fopen('somefile.txt','a');
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what mc10 wrote?

Comment: Yes :-) I'm using IPod and I didn't saw that answer came. Sorry